# Is the Muffin Man in Shrek an allusion to the old woman from the Gingerbread Man fairytale?

Tags: shrek

In the Gingerbread Man fairytale, it was an old woman who made Gingy.

But in Shrek, it was the Muffin Man who made him.

So IS he an allusion to the old woman from the original fairytale? If not, could the “she” who Gingy refers to in Shrek 1 be her?

Comment: It seems fairly clear to me that they've simply conflated two fairy tale characters.

Comment: @Valorum conflation makes for an acceptable answer, so you should post it.

Comment: Can you quote the line where Gingy refers to a "she"? Also, I couldn't quite tell from your question, but did you know "the muffin man" is himself a character in an old nursery rhyme, separate from the gingerbread man fairy tale?

Comment: @Hypnosifl know the Muffin Man is a separate character, but he was the one who made the Gingerbread Man in Shrek, and in the original fairytale, it was an old woman who made him. Also, here’s the quote:

Comment: Gingy: Well, she’s married to the Muffin Man.

Comment: The context of that line is [here](https://www.quotes.net/mquote/1197388), Farquaad is interrogating Gingy and wants to know who is hiding some still-uncaught fairy tale creatures. The joke is just that they're repeating a slightly distorted version of the "muffin man" rhyme, I don't think it's important who "she" is or that the writers likely gave it any thought.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The quick answer is that there's no connection between the gingerbreadman and the muffin man, although both are kind of warnings.

The Muffin Man is a reference to accepting cookies (or muffins) from strangers -- in real life a serial killer of children in particular. (start with: https://en.uncyclopedia.co/wiki/The_Muffin_Man to get the flavour)

The gingerbread man was more akin to Aesop's frog fable, or the one with the scorpion -- sometimes accepting help is the greatest danger...

The thing is, Shrek "borrowed" ideas and concepts from many different sources, especially old folk tales and nursery rhymes.

Comment: That uncyclopedia article is about a murderer who was given the nickname "muffin man" based on a pre-existing children's song, the original "do you know the muffin man" song doesn't suggest anything sinister about the muffin man, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Muffin_Man) for the history.

Comment: Can you provide a source that's a little less suspect than that page?  I mean, it's fashionable to look down on Wikipedia, but at least there's some attempt to source things.  The page you're referencing appears to be [made of whole cloth](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/muffin-man-song-serial-killer/).